# Stacked geom_bar with ascending bars

Tags: stack, fill, geom-bar

I try to make a geom_bar with ascending bars. On the Y-axis, it is how I want it, but in the bars, it doesn't work. I try to order the stacked bars by starting the most common drug and ends with the least common drug. This is the code of the geom_bar

```
ggplot(data = Antibiotica2.1) +
  aes(
x = reorder(Specialisme, -Freq_totaal), 
y = Frequentie,
fill = reorder(MedicatienaamNieuw, +Frequentie)) +
  geom_bar(
stat = "identity", 
position = "stack") +
  theme(
plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
aspect.ratio = 4/3) +
  labs(fill='Antibiotica') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#984ea3", "#fed9a6", "#ffffb3", "#e5d8bd", "#beaed4", "#e41a1c", "#4daf4a", "#D55E00", "#0072B2")) +
 coord_flip()
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

I don't know how to insert my dataframe here in the right way. But this is a picture of it.
[image]

How do I have to shaping the 'fill = reorder' part of the code?